# Grant View All Accounts permission for a Community User

Tags: security, sharing, customer-community, permission-sets, view

We have a community and community users holds `customer community login` profile. Basically, `Account` and `ChildObject__c` have been shared with community users with a sharing set according to the below rules.

`User.Contact.Account = Account.Id`

`ChildObject__c.Contact__c = ChildObject__c.Contact__c`

This way a particular community user can view his parent account. All the community users have been created under the same account named "**Community User Account**". So that each community user can only see **Community User Account**.

But there is a set of special community users(they share the same profile and created under the same account) who has assigned to a permission set called "**Account Admins**". `ChildObject__c` has a lookup to `Account`. So we need this **Account Admins** to view `ChildObject__c.Account__c` records as well. (In addition to their own Account).

Any help to achieve this is much appreciated.

Comment: can you show the sharing set rules you have tried?

Comment: Hey, sharing sets are there in the description. For your reference, they are as follows.  `User.Contact.Account = Account.Id` and `ChildObject__c.Contact__c = ChildObject__c.Contact__c`

Comment: i think this has to be done with two profiles - one for admins and one for everyone else. To have different sharing set rules on the same sobject (ChildObject__c) means multiple profiles